# instanceof in Java - why doesn't it compile when comparing incompatible types?

Tags: java, instanceof

```
class A {

    public static void main(String...args) {
        Integer var = 10; 

        if(var instanceof Character)  // Line1
            System.out.println("var is a Character");
    }
}
```

I know *Line 1* will not compile because the compiler has found that `var` is not a `Character`.

What I fail to understand is why the compiler throws an error instead of returning `false` or `true`.

If the compiler returns `false` or `true` (i.e treating the `instanceof` operation like a regular if-based validation), then it be much more useful.. would it not?

Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Change `Integer var = 10;` to `Object var = 10;`. The compiler is telling you that `var` can **never** be `instanceof Character` if you declare it an `Integer`.

Comment: I suppose if you want something similar to an `instanceof` check but instead of throwing an error it will return `false`, you could try `Character.class.isInstance(var)` which will return false in this case.

Comment: @JoshM see my comment on the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18548547/2071828). The JLS specifies that an error is thrown for a good reason. If you just had to _write_ that `var` is an `Integer` why on earth would you then want to check that it isn't? Unless you have an exceptionally short memory...

Comment: @BoristheSpider True, I don't think he is concerned with how straightforward his example is (you could obviously see that `var` is an `Integer` so the `instanceof` check is obviously pointless) but I think he just wants to generally know the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a compilation error in accordance with [JLS §15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> **If a cast of the *RelationalExpression* to the *ReferenceType* would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the `instanceof` relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the `instanceof` expression could never be true.**

*RelationalExpression* is the first operand of `instanceof` and *ReferenceType* is the second.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the arshajii's answer, if you want to avoid compile-time error and want run-time true/false result for checking whether var is instance of Character, then use code like this:

```
if(var.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Character.class))
    System.out.println("var is a Character");
else
    System.out.println("var is NOT a Character");
```

As you would expect it will print:

> var is not a Character

Comment: I think the fundamental point of the JLS is that this check can **never** return `true` if you know that the type is not assignable. This is entirely pointless - if you know it's an `Integer` then this check is redundant, `return false` would work just as well. If you do not know that the `var` is an `Integer`, i.e. you have an `Object`, then `instanceof` will compile just fine.

Comment: it's useful, if I want do less code in some case. I have crosswalk project in shared mode at develop phase and a embedded mode for production, I use `if (this instanceof XWalkActivity)` to check, but it compile error. `https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/shared_mode.html`